# WADL2JAVA JClass name empty error from command line tool

Tags: java, wadl

I am trying to use the wadl2java command line tool to generate the client side stubs for a wadl I have been provided with, but I am getting a JClass name empty error. Can anyone help me to resolve this? I can't seem to find much trouble shooting info around this.

the fullstack trace is

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   JClass name empty     at
>   com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass.(JDefinedClass.java:194)
>     at
>   com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass.(JDefinedClass.java:154)
>     at
>   com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass._class(JDefinedClass.java:631)
>     at
>   com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass._class(JDefinedClass.java:606)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.ws.wadl2java.ResourceClassGenerator.generateClass(ResourceClassGenerator.java:132)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.ws.wadl2java.Wadl2Java.generateSubClass(Wadl2Java.java:406)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.ws.wadl2java.Wadl2Java.generateEndpointClass(Wadl2Java.java:384)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.ws.wadl2java.Wadl2Java.process(Wadl2Java.java:146)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.ws.wadl2java.Main.main(Main.java:120)

Answer (score 2):

In your wadl file if you have path with out value then you get this exception. It is known bug. To solve it just add path insted or empty.

```
<resource path="/">
```

above lead error.

Correct one is

```
<resource path="/MyClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

We've seen additonal  types with empty PATH using Jersey to generate the wadl.  Manually removing the extra  lines resolves the problem.